Is this a valid partition of $\mathbb{N}$?
I was working on exercise $1.2.4$ on Abbott’s Understanding Analysis which states
Produce an infinite collection of sets $A_1, A_2, A_3, …$ with the property that every $A_i$ has an infinite number of elements, $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for all $i \neq j$, and $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} A_i = \mathbb{N}$
My proposed solution is the following:
Let $A_1 = P \cup \lbrace 1 \rbrace$ where $P$ is the set of prime numbers. For $n>1$ we define $A_n = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{N} : x = p_1 \cdot … \cdot p_n \rbrace$ where $p_i \in P$.
Since $A_n$ is well defined for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and there are infinitely many primes, it is evident that there are infinitely many $A_i$ and that each of them is infinite.
We show that for $i\neq j$, $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ by contradiction. Suppose $i \neq j$ and the intersection is not empty, which means there is at least one element in the intersection. Let $m\in A_i \cap A_j$ be that element. By definition of the sets $A_i$ and $A_j$, we get that $m$ has two distinct prime factorizations, which is impossible by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Therefore, $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ (or $i=j$).
Using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic we show that the union $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} A_i = \mathbb{N}$. For any $x \in \mathbb{N}$ we know that $x = p_1 \cdot … \cdot p_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $x\in A_n$. Conversely, let $a\in \bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} A_i$. This means that $a \in A_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Since every $A_i$ is a set of natural numbers, $a\in \mathbb{N}$. This shows that $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} A_i = \mathbb{N}$.
My question to you is, is this solution valid? If not, why?. Also, any tips/advice on my writing is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Looks fine to me.

It looks good to me. In the first half of the second part of the proof, you should say "we know that $x = p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_n$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and some list of primes $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$".

In other words, you are partitioning $\Bbb N$ based on the value of the prime $\Omega$ function (with a special case for $1$). There are infinitely many possible values of $\Omega(n)$ and each value (except 0) occurs for infinitely many $n$, so this works. You could also have used $\omega$. Another common choice for this exercise is the 2-adic valuation.
